# String Split In JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have gone through a lot of answers and walkthrough here but nothing seems to work fine! Here is what I want: I want to split string by " " which is pretty much easy: this is what i did:

```
var data = response.data.split(" ");
```

and believing this should give me an array which will allow me do something like this:

> data[0], data[1]...

just like that, which means if I have a string like this

> var data = src/ .gitignore Calculator.apk build.gradle proguard-rules.pro

and I split it with " ", I should now have

> data[0]=src/, data[1]=.gitignore
>    bla bla bla...

but what I keep on getting is just one index of array! i.e

> data[0] = src/\n.gitignore\nCalculator.apk\nbuild.gradle\nproguard-rules.pro

Only. And I still can't understand why this is happening!

Comment: It looks like the space between those is a new line not a simple white space. Try: `response.data.split("\n");`

Comment: I see nothing in this question about AngularJS, nor the completely different framework Angular...

Comment: Please provide the actual output of `console.log(response.data)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's the escape character `\n` for a new line. Try splitting with `/( |\n)/`. That'll take care of the new line as well as the space.

Comment: It's still appear the same! ["src/\n.gitignore\nCalculator.apk\nbuild.gradle\nproguard-rules.pro"]

Comment: Try with only `\n`.

Comment: thanks! it finally worked, I think you should update your answer so I can accept it as the correct answer.

Answer (score -2):

try

```
var data = 'src/ .gitignore Calculator.apk build.gradle proguard-rules.pro';
console.log(data.split(/\s/));
```

Comment: It appeared the way I it from the console but not on the browser

Comment: As posted by the OP, it's *not* a space.

Comment: @weirdpanda go check what `/\s/` includes